# Allow users to grant permissions to other users for their account in ASP.NET Identity 2.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

Let's assume I have my ASP.NET MVC 5 application (using Identity 2.0) where users are allowed to register. When a user register (Mr. X) he is added automatically to role `User`. Now I would like that user to be able to add/grant access to other users and those users to be able to login and see the same resources/data as Mr. X. Mr. X should be able to manage all the users he/she adds to the application. For the whole application Mr. X is just a normal user, but he acts as an Admin for the users he adds.

Can somebody explain how this can be achieved? Basically:
- an user should be able to invite other users
- the invited users should be managed by the user whom invited them
- all new users should see everything what the original user (who invited them) sees

This should work basically like permissions work in SharePoint or Groups in LinkedIn

Comment: It is unlikely you'll get answers to this, as there are too many questions packed into 2 paragraphs. Basically, the question is too broad and you'll need to narrow down your problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AS per your requirement it seems like it's kind of CRM application with user segregation and management.

You Need to have a proper Role/Person Management for this:

**Query**

Now I would like that user to be able to add/grant access to other users and those users to be able to login and see the same resources/data as Mr. X.

**Solution**

Create a Table `UserManagement` Like:

```
ID    UserId                AddedByPersonId
1     1024(New User)        1011(Mr. X ID)
2     1025(New User)        1011(Mr. X ID)
```

So When a New User registers or is added

The `UserManagement` Table will be updated

In this way Mr. X will have control over all the users whom he has added or Invited.

Hope it Helps.

Thanks,

Comment: This Answer is marked by MVC Expert Rick Anderson : https://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-recommended-resources#qand Q: How can I gran users permissions to add other users to certain roles?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a new role for each user.  You can probably just name the role using the UserId, and then add users that he grants to that role so you have a way to track this hierarchy.  The rough idea seems doable...